# Call to two buttons from the same page is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC5 application with a table and when you click on create it navigates to new page with a form to put data and save. Currently this is working fine, the problem is that I need to add an additional button which calls new action but will not navigate to other page, just call it and get a response.

When I put the following 2 buttons in different pages both of them work fine, but when I add them to the same page the second button calls the create action of the first.

How to avoid that ?

This is the save button which call to the create action

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="actbtn" value="Create"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the second button that **works fine in a different page** and when I copy it 
to the create page it calls the **create action**. I know that this is because of the **submit** but how should I avoid it?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "User", new { Name = Model.Name }))
    {
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Check" />
        <span id='result'></span>
    }
```

How should I call the action check in controller user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourSaveActionName", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="actbtn" value="Create"  />
         </div>
      </div>
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "User", new { Name = Model.Name }))
{
     <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Check" />
     <span id='result'></span>
}
```

Comment: I try it and I've the same issue ,when I click on the second button i got error 404 and in in the URL is see the path action/controller ,how to avoid it,I wanted to stay in the same page and stop by BP in the action...

Comment: use this @using (Html.BeginForm("YourSaveActionName", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })), or check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks ,I add it and nothing has changed :(,any other idea ?

Comment: show me your complete html code, You must be missing something. As this works for me in my project for 5 buttons on single page.

Answer (score 2):

Add a name attribute to each buttons like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" />
```

In Controller Action,

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(string buttonType)
{
  if (buttonType == "Send")
     {
          // add your stuffs for the first button 
     }
  else
     {
          // add your stuffs for the second buttonbutton
     }
}
```